# how to upload a file from php to amqp

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

i want to know... how can i send a file to a rabbitmq queue from php.
i have gone through many examples most of them didnt work.
below is a consumer producer example which is near to working.
Below is a the publisher.php

```
<?php
  require_once('../php-amqplib/amqp.inc');
    include('../config.php');
    $conn = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS, VHOST);
    $channel = $conn->channel();
    $channel->exchange_declare('upload-pictures','direct', false, true, false);
    $metadata = json_encode(array(
    'image_id' => $argv[1],
    'user_id' => $argv[2],
    'image_path' => $argv[3]
    ));
    $msg = new AMQPMessage($metadata, array('content_type' => 'text/plain','delivery_mode'    => 2));
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, 'upload-pictures');
    $channel->close();
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

consumer.php

```
<?php
require_once('../php-amqplib/amqp.inc');
include('../config.php');
$conn = new AMQPConnection(HOST, PORT, USER, PASS,VHOST);
$channel = $conn->channel();
$queue = 'add-points';
$consumer_tag = 'consumer';
$channel->exchange_declare('upload-pictures','direct', false, true, false);
$channel->queue_declare('add-points',false, true, false, false);
$channel->queue_bind('add-points', 'upload-pictures');
$consumer = function($msg){};
$channel->basic_consume($queue,$consumer_tag,false,false,false,false,$consumer);
?>
```

according to the example provided in the rabbitmq manual, i need to run consumer(php consumer.php) first in one terminal and the publisher (php publisher.php 1 2 file/path.png) in another terminal,
i will get a "Adding points to user: 2" message in the consumer terminal. iam not getting this message at all. can you suggest where iam going wrong

Comment: can you provide a link to manual you followed?

Answer (score 6):

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:**

AMQP protocol is not aimed for large content transfer (but it can do such job, I tried up to 128Mb for testing). **I will suggest you to send path to file in message and process it in worker rather than sending whole file**, while storing large message eat memory very fast and when it exceed disk will be used, which is pretty slow, comparing to RAM.

---

**Anyway, if you still want to send file:**

You have to send file content as regular message body. If it is a binary file, then encode it with base64 or whatever you want. There is no other way to do what you want. In your code I didn't see that you are reading file.

Comment: i added a wait function along with a callback function..its working now :) :)....file which i want to upload are very less in size max size of 25mb. and yes iam just sending a file path. the consumer will have code to read the file.